# .NET bug in BigInteger?

Tags: c#, .net, biginteger

I've been working on a .NET project where I need BigIntegers and I've noticed that the framework's implementation delivers what appears to be incorrect results. After hours of trying to find what I'm doing wrong I decided to test my algorithm in Java and C++ (using OpenSSL) and shockingly in both languages I get the expected results.

Now I'm naturally wondering what I'm doing wrong (since there is no way on earth this is a bug that hasn't been noticed before) and I hope someone can help me!

This is the reduced C# code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var B = BigInteger.Parse("023B61801145A9CB06ADF77493042D166E793B946D1B07B46070E3986A6F036BE", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        var k = BigInteger.Parse("3", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        var x = BigInteger.Parse("09F015DB40A59403E42FBD568AF5774A0A0488A62", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        var g = BigInteger.Parse("7", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        var N = BigInteger.Parse("0894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B290650530801B18EBFBF5E8FAB3C82872A3E9BB7", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        var u = BigInteger.Parse("0AC06F615645BEA9B3D6D887C30D28D71B079B598", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        var a = BigInteger.Parse("0D4515CA7747787F1DDA9962ACE81E8412D9D20D06251696ACD74735F1F3B9875", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

        var S = calc(B, k, x, g, N, u, a);
        Console.WriteLine(S.ToString("X"));
    }

    static BigInteger calc(BigInteger B, BigInteger k, BigInteger x, BigInteger g, BigInteger N, BigInteger u, BigInteger a)
    {
        var val = B - k * BigInteger.ModPow(g, x, N);
        var exponent = a + u * x;
        return BigInteger.ModPow(val, exponent, N);
    }
}
```

You can execute it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qXXiBk

Same code in Java:

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    BigInteger B = new BigInteger("023B61801145A9CB06ADF77493042D166E793B946D1B07B46070E3986A6F036BE", 16);
    BigInteger k = new BigInteger("3", 16);
    BigInteger x = new BigInteger("09F015DB40A59403E42FBD568AF5774A0A0488A62", 16);
    BigInteger g = new BigInteger("7", 16);
    BigInteger N = new BigInteger("0894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B290650530801B18EBFBF5E8FAB3C82872A3E9BB7", 16);
    BigInteger u = new BigInteger("0AC06F615645BEA9B3D6D887C30D28D71B079B598", 16);
    BigInteger a = new BigInteger("0D4515CA7747787F1DDA9962ACE81E8412D9D20D06251696ACD74735F1F3B9875", 16);

    BigInteger S = calc(B, k, x, g, N, u, a);
    System.out.println(S.toString(16));
  }

  private static BigInteger calc(BigInteger B, BigInteger k, BigInteger x, BigInteger g, BigInteger N, BigInteger u, BigInteger a)
  {
    BigInteger value = B.subtract(k.multiply(g.modPow(x, N)));
    BigInteger exponent = a.add(u.multiply(x));

    return value.modPow(exponent, N);
  }
}
```

You can execute it here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/BJXxMiO28

And finally a quick and dirty C++ implementation using OpenSSL:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

 #include <openssl/bn.h>

 class BigInteger
 {
     public:
        BigInteger(char const* hexString, BN_CTX *ctx)
            : bn_{BN_new()}
            , ctx_{ctx}
        {
            BN_hex2bn(&bn_, hexString);
        }

        ~BigInteger()
        {
            BN_free(bn_);
        }

        BigInteger ModPow(BigInteger const& exponent, BigInteger const& modulo) const
        {
            BigInteger ret{"0", ctx_};
             BN_mod_exp(ret.bn_, bn_, exponent.bn_, modulo.bn_, ctx_);
             return ret;
        }

        BigInteger Subtract(BigInteger const& rhs) const
        {
            BigInteger ret{"0", ctx_};
            BN_sub(ret.bn_, bn_, rhs.bn_);
             return ret;
        }

        BigInteger Multiply(BigInteger const& rhs) const
        {
            BigInteger ret{"0", ctx_};
            BN_mul(ret.bn_, bn_, rhs.bn_, ctx_);
             return ret;
        }

        BigInteger Add(BigInteger const& rhs) const
        {
            BigInteger ret{"0", ctx_};
            BN_add(ret.bn_, bn_, rhs.bn_);
             return ret;
        }

        std::string ToString() const
        {
            return BN_bn2hex(bn_);
        }

     private:
     BIGNUM* bn_;
     BN_CTX *ctx_;
 };

BigInteger calc(BigInteger const& B, BigInteger const& k, BigInteger const& x, BigInteger const& g, BigInteger const& N, BigInteger const& u, BigInteger const& a)
{
    BigInteger value = B.Subtract(k.Multiply(g.ModPow(x, N)));
    BigInteger exponent = a.Add(u.Multiply(x));

    return value.ModPow(exponent, N);
}

int main()
{
     BN_CTX *ctx = BN_CTX_new();

    BigInteger B{"023B61801145A9CB06ADF77493042D166E793B946D1B07B46070E3986A6F036BE", ctx};
    BigInteger k{"3", ctx};
    BigInteger x{"09F015DB40A59403E42FBD568AF5774A0A0488A62", ctx};
    BigInteger g{"7", ctx};
    BigInteger N{"0894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B290650530801B18EBFBF5E8FAB3C82872A3E9BB7", ctx};
    BigInteger u{"0AC06F615645BEA9B3D6D887C30D28D71B079B598", ctx};
    BigInteger a{"0D4515CA7747787F1DDA9962ACE81E8412D9D20D06251696ACD74735F1F3B9875", ctx};

    auto S = calc(B, k, x, g, N, u, a);

    std::cout << S.ToString();
    BN_CTX_free(ctx);
}
```

You can execute it here: https://godbolt.org/z/PtNGdQ

Again, both C++ and Java agree on the answer beeing `218BC3CE2641EFF5F4BB95A2DB931CA62A933C6BA40D3F6E2AD5D5F7D41F0E0A` and only C# says it's `98405F6F9C609C9A370E3A17B28CCC5322918ADCE44DE0DE7F995370A9E07253`. This is an actual show-stopper since I need to work on systems that require the first (correct) answer. I'm really at a loss here and I sincerely hope that somebody knows what I'm doing wrong.

Cheers

Comment: Have you ever tried Int64 instead of BigInteger?

Comment: @AliKianoor These numbers don't fit in `Int64` - that's the whole point of `BigInteger`.

Comment: try this one: BigInteger.Parse(hexString, NumberStyles.Any); maybe 'Any' can solve the problem.

Comment: @AliKianoor Why do you think that will help when it's already established that the hexadecimal strings are being parsed correctly in all 3 platforms?

Comment: Even using the decimal values and no flags still generates the incorrect answer (or all other platforms and also python are wrong and only c# is correct... I didn't check the computation myself by hand or with my own big integer code).

Comment: @SirRufo I don't believe so, I get the same results from C# and Java **after** the `ModPow` call. Things only get different at `d = B - m` in my wiki answer below.

Comment: @Dai Your wiki answer is wrong

Comment: @SirRufo It's a wiki after-all, please update it if you think it can be improved :)

Comment: @Dai use ToString() in C# and toString(10) in Java and you will get comparable results

Comment: @Dai I tried to improve the answer - but honestly the best improvement would be its deletion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python also agrees the answer should be `218bc3ce2641eff5f4bb95a2db931ca62a933c6ba40d3f6e2ad5d5f7d41f0e0a`

and the problem doesn't seem the hex parsing (even parsing the decimal version of the values the result is the same).

I think you've the correct attitude about thinking that's not possible that it's a bug in the big integer in that C# implementation, but this actually seems to me a screaming evidence this is the case (even if I must say I'm not a C# programmer, only played with it a bit).

<strike>You should in my opinion file a bug report.</strike>

EDIT

As Sir Rufo pointed out correctly in the comments the problem is in how modulo operation is handled in C# for negative dividends, changing the code to

```
var val = (B - k * BigInteger.ModPow(g, x, N) + N*k) % N;
```

produces the expected result.

I would say still a bug, but a design bug and not going to be fixed.

Comment: Very interesting! I'd also say it's very much unlikely that this will get fixed since I'd assume a lot of code depends on this weird behaviour. Thank you so much for looking into this!

Answer (score 3):

## Information

Lets have a look inside the `calc` method:

When we compare the hex output values in C# `val.ToString("X")` and Java `val.toString(16)` we will get different outputs:

```
C#:   F4EB82A8CAFDA89F0E2B69C3C4FEF2920913B60DD701C2193C41AE7EC6BC1A38B
Java: -b147d5735025760f1d4963c3b010d6df6ec49f228fe3de6c3be51813943e5c75
```

but when we use the decimal output values in C# `val.ToString()` and Java `val.toString(10)` we will get the same outputs:

```
C#:   -80186293521643543106092742417459818853945355375849134884320433064971933211765
Java: -80186293521643543106092742417459818853945355375849134884320433064971933211765
```

**This answer is based on a comparison (hex outputs) which you cannot compare.**

---

(Posting this as an answer because this won't fit into a comment, but making it a community wiki):

The difference between the C# and Java versions happens inside `calc`. When I separate-out the intermediate values like so:

#### CSharp

```
BigInteger B = BigInteger.Parse("023B61801145A9CB06ADF77493042D166E793B946D1B07B46070E3986A6F036BE", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
BigInteger k = BigInteger.Parse("3", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
BigInteger g = BigInteger.Parse("7", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
BigInteger x = BigInteger.Parse("09F015DB40A59403E42FBD568AF5774A0A0488A62", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
BigInteger N = BigInteger.Parse("0894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B290650530801B18EBFBF5E8FAB3C82872A3E9BB7", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

Console.WriteLine( "B == " + B.ToString("X") );
Console.WriteLine( "k == " + k.ToString("X") );
Console.WriteLine( "g == " + g.ToString("X") );
Console.WriteLine( "x == " + x.ToString("X") );
Console.WriteLine( "N == " + N.ToString("X") );

Console.WriteLine( "-------" );

BigInteger p = BigInteger.ModPow(g, x, N);
Console.WriteLine( "p == " + p.ToString("X") );

BigInteger m = k * p;
Console.WriteLine( "m == " + m.ToString("X") );

BigInteger d = B - m;
Console.WriteLine("d == " + d.ToString("X"));
```

#### Java

```
BigInteger B = new BigInteger("023B61801145A9CB06ADF77493042D166E793B946D1B07B46070E3986A6F036BE", 16);
BigInteger k = new BigInteger("3", 16);
BigInteger g = new BigInteger("7", 16);
BigInteger x = new BigInteger("09F015DB40A59403E42FBD568AF5774A0A0488A62", 16);
BigInteger N = new BigInteger("0894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B290650530801B18EBFBF5E8FAB3C82872A3E9BB7", 16);

System.out.println("B == " + B.toString(16));
System.out.println("k == " + k.toString(16));
System.out.println("g == " + g.toString(16));
System.out.println("x == " + x.toString(16));
System.out.println("N == " + N.toString(16));

System.out.println("-------");

BigInteger p = g.modPow(x, N);
System.out.println("p == " + p.toString(16));

BigInteger m = k.multiply(p);
System.out.println("m == " + m.toString(16));

BigInteger d = B.subtract(m);
System.out.println("d == " + d.toString(16));
```

These gives me this output:

#### CSharp:

```
B == 23B61801145A9CB06ADF77493042D166E793B946D1B07B46070E3986A6F036BE
k == 3
g == 7
x == 09F015DB40A59403E42FBD568AF5774A0A0488A62
N == 0894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B290650530801B18EBFBF5E8FAB3C82872A3E9BB7
-------
p == 46FF4F26CC2AB0EA82B849044AC68D6CC772C8232086C890C0FBC5DE13BA3111
m == 0D4FDED74648012BF8828DB0CE053A84656585869619459B242F3519A3B2E9333
value == F4EB82A8CAFDA89F0E2B69C3C4FEF2920913B60DD701C2193C41AE7EC6BC1A38B
```

#### Java:

```
B == 23b61801145a9cb06adf77493042d166e793b946d1b07b46070e3986a6f036be                                                                                                 
k == 3                                                                                                                                                                
g == 7                                                                                                                                                                
x == 9f015db40a59403e42fbd568af5774a0a0488a62                                                                                                                         
N == 894b645e89e1535bbdad5b8b290650530801b18ebfbf5e8fab3c82872a3e9bb7                                                                                                 
-------                                                                                                                                                               
p == 46ff4f26cc2ab0ea82b849044ac68d6cc772c8232086c890c0fbc5de13ba3111                                                                                                 
m == d4fded74648012bf8828db0ce053a84656585869619459b242f3519a3b2e9333                                                                                                 
d == -b147d5735025760f1d4963c3b010d6df6ec49f228fe3de6c3be51813943e5c75
```

So it's something weird going on in `B - m` and **not** the `ModPow` call.

### Part 2

Let's reduce this case down to `d = B - m` by serializing the `BigInteger` values (I verified they're being serialized correctly):

#### CSharp

```
BigInteger B = BigInteger.Parse("023B61801145A9CB06ADF77493042D166E793B946D1B07B46070E3986A6F036BE", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
Console.WriteLine( "B == " + B.ToString("X") )

BigInteger m = new BigInteger( new Byte[] { 51, 147, 46, 59, 154, 81, 243, 66, 178, 89, 148, 97, 105, 88, 88, 86, 70, 168, 83, 224, 12, 219, 40, 136, 191, 18, 128, 100, 116, 237, 253, 212, 0 } );
Console.WriteLine( "m == " + m.ToString("X") )

BigInteger d = B - m;
Console.WriteLine( "d == " + d.ToString("X") )
```

#### Java:

```
BigInteger B = new BigInteger("023B61801145A9CB06ADF77493042D166E793B946D1B07B46070E3986A6F036BE", 16);
BigInteger m = new BigInteger( new byte[] { 0, -44, -3, -19, 116, 100, -128, 18, -65, -120, 40, -37, 12, -32, 83, -88, 70, 86, 88, 88, 105, 97, -108, 89, -78, 66, -13, 81, -102, 59, 46, -109, 51 } );

System.out.println("B == " + B.toString(16));
System.out.println("m == " + m.toString(16));

BigInteger d = B.subtract(m);
System.out.println("d == " + d.toString(16));
```

This shows that both C# and Java have the same values for `B` and `m` and different values for `d`:

```
// C#:
B == 23B61801145A9CB06ADF77493042D166E793B946D1B07B46070E3986A6F036BE
m == 0D4FDED74648012BF8828DB0CE053A84656585869619459B242F3519A3B2E9333
d == F4EB82A8CAFDA89F0E2B69C3C4FEF2920913B60DD701C2193C41AE7EC6BC1A38B

// Java:
B == 23b61801145a9cb06adf77493042d166e793b946d1b07b46070e3986a6f036be                                                                                
m == d4fded74648012bf8828db0ce053a84656585869619459b242f3519a3b2e9333                                                                                
d == -b147d5735025760f1d4963c3b010d6df6ec49f228fe3de6c3be51813943e5c75
```

The question is - does `F4EB82A8CAFDA89F0E2B69C3C4FEF2920913B60DD701C2193C41AE7EC6BC1A38B` represent the same value as `-b147d5735025760f1d4963c3b010d6df6ec49f228fe3de6c3be51813943e5c75`?

Comment: Seems the difference in how hex conversion displays negative values; what you found is a display difference.

Comment: Your are not comparing the real results, just presentations of the values and the hex presenters are different for C# and Java.